# Can I use the same conda environment for different Django projects?

Tags: python, django, conda

I know that environments are used for backward-compatibility and to create a box where we can download packages without affecting the rest of the computer.

I am working on a couple of django projects and I was wondering if I need to create a new conda environment for each new project or can I use the same one? What might go wrong if I use the same environment for similar web-development project?

Comment: [this may help you](https://towardsdatascience.com/virtual-environments-104c62d48c54)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same conda environment for 2 or more projects , it is ok for local setup but when you deploy you will have to filter all the unwanted requirements

Comment: What if both projects use the same libraries/packages? then, there could be  not filtering?

Comment: Yes , if you projects require same libraries and packages then no need to filter.